# asp.net mvc identity form doesn't post to allowanonymous action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, post, asp.net-identity

I am learning identity and I have a problem that seems like nobody has. My login to application works just fine if I put in the action by itself, but if I try to make it like usually logins should be - with form and post. Then my form data just doesn't make it to the action. I have a breakpoint in that action and the code just never hits. I don't have things like AntiForgeryToken, because I just want to hit the breakpoint.

**Login Action**

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
        public virtual ActionResult Login(UserViewModel user, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return RedirectToAction(MVC.Home.ActionNames.Index, MVC.Home.Name);

            var result = SignInManager.PasswordSignIn(
                user.Name, user.Password, false, shouldLockout: false);

            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);

                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:

                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:

                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt");
                    return RedirectToAction(MVC.Home.ActionNames.Index, MVC.Home.Name);
            }
        }
```

**Login HTML**

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Admin", new { returnUrl = ViewBag.returnUrl }, FormMethod.Post ))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
        <div class="input-group">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new {@class = "form-control", placeholder = "Jméno"})
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
        </div>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
        <div class="input-group">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Heslo" })
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
        </div>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
        <div class="input-group">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Potvrdit heslo" })
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
        </div>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Přihlásit se" class="btn btn-default"/>
}
```

**Startup.Auth**

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString($"/{MVC.Admin.Name}/{MVC.Admin.ActionNames.Login}")
        });
    }
```

Comment: Do you get any errors when posting the form?

Comment: The code you have shown works fine. If its not working for you its because of code you have not shown us. And what do you mean by _works just fine if I put in the action by itself_

Comment: Post works fine. I checked it browser developer tools and it is posted with success. I will try to create new project and copy paste everything to the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the action that returned Login View. I didn't pass model as object to my view as a parameter.